# Sweave on Windows 7 - using Texmaker

Tags: miktex, texmaker, windows, r, sweave

So I've tried to configue Sweave on Texmaker following these instructions: http://arts.uwaterloo.ca/~tmparker/722/hw/Setup_Sweave_in_Texmaker.pdf

When I go to run this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{Sweave Example 1}
\author{Friedrich Leisch}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

In this example we embed parts of the examples from the
\texttt{kruskal.test} help page into a \LaTeX{} document:

<<>>=
data(airquality)
library(ctest)
kruskal.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@
which shows that the location parameter of the Ozone 
distribution varies significantly from month to month. Finally we
include a boxplot of the data:

\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

saving it as a .Rnw file and clicking `Tools -> R Sweave`, the message log at the bottom of Texmaker 'Error: could not start the command'. I've saved it in a directory with no spaces and followed the above link setup exactly.

Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: If you have the message "could not start the command", it means that the syntax of the command is wrong or the executable launched by the command doesn’t exist or the executable is not in the windows path (or you have not the permission to launch it). This message is displayed when the system can't launch the command (and returns an error).

Comment: Is there a way to amend this so it can run? I'm pretty sure the above syntax is correct.

Comment: @hgeop may be `R Sweave` executable path is not set in `Configure TeXmaker`-->`Commands` to let TeXmaker know the executable properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem described above and even following the instructions cited, couldn't solve the problem. So I tried to use knitr instead Sweave and everythig is fine now. Here is what I did:

1. Install the package `knitr` on R;
2. On TeXmaker > User > User commands > Edit User commands: choose command `1`;
3. Configure the user command `1` as follow:

   - On menu item type: `knitr`
   - On command, type (with the quotes):

     `Rscript.exe -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"` for Texmaker on Windows

     `Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"` for Texmaker on Ubuntu
   - Click OK
4. Open the `.Rnw` file
5. Choose `1:knitr` on compile options, then compile the file
6. Run `PDFLaTeX` on the file.
7. Open the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've managed to implement both `sweave` and `knitr` now

Comment: How do you embed/mix this code  from a rnw file with other code on a tex file?